# Change user home directory without root access

Tags: linux

I have an account on a server (the admin is crappy) and he set my user home at `/home/username`. He also took away my access to this user directory, and said I should use `/home/Guest` which is `root:root` and public writable (permissions `777`).

As I don’t want to use it, I thought I will make a sub directory of /home/Guest which is not public writable, and set it as my home. unfortunately

```
usermod -m -d /home/Guest/dir username
```

Failed with command not found. What can I do (I already contacted him), to get some home folder (he denied, I don't know why)

Comment: Unfortunately, your only option is to work with whomever has root access to the server. First, `usermod` is probably installed on the system but `sbin` isn't in your path since you're not a root user. Second, AFAIK, only the root user or a user with root permissions can modify the `passwd` file which is used to determine your home directory.

Comment: you might be able to create files inside home directory without root access like this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138162/how-can-i-create-files-in-my-home-directory-without-root other than that root was the only option AFAIk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this temporarily. This means that every time you login as that user you have to run this one command:

```
export HOME=/home/Guest/dir
```

This way, you can make most applications *think* that your home directory is whatever location you use above.

`~` will also start to point to `/home/Guest/dir`.

The applications this worked with for me were NPM and Maven.

Comment: Ages ago..... Interesting how naïve I was :) tho accepted the answer!